# sqlalchemy некорректно отрабатывает условие фильтра: q.filter(table1.name1 != table2.name2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть приложение на `flask`, используется `sqlalchemy`. Есть запрос, в который вставляю `.filter()`

Вопрос следующий: Почему такой код

```
q.filter(Transaction.transaction_id == ReconciledTransaction.safe_withdraw_id)
```

отрабатывает корректно, а вот этот

```
q.filter(Transaction.transaction_id != ReconciledTransaction.safe_withdraw_id)
```

работает неправильно (фильтр в этом случае тупо игнорируется)?

Comment: а можно больше подробностей, фильтр не может игнорироваться, либо выдаст результат, либо ошибку, что Вы ему даете и что получаете?

Comment: @IgorSergeevich Грубо говоря, запрос забирает список всех транзакций, припихивает туда джоинами информацию о клиенте(которая не содержит никаких транзакций), и фильтром я пытаюсь отсеять транзакции, которые присутствуют в таблице `ReconciledTransaction`, ни в первом ни во втором случае нет ошибок, код не валится, просто в первом случае фильтр срабатывает(выдаются только те транзакции, которые есть в `ReconciledTransaction`), а во втором случае не срабатывает(выдаются все транзакции).

Comment: А Вы уверены, что во втором случае у вас присутствуют транзакции, которые есть в `ReconciledTransaction.safe_withdraw_id`?

Comment: @IgorSergeevich Более чем, ведь сам запрос вообще не меняется, я меняю только условие фильтра

Comment: Добавьте приниты и сравните питоном по условиям `== & is & type()` может там закралось число - строка?

Comment: @jfs Проблема уже решена, сейчас в ответ кину решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогли на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440663/strange-filter-behavior-in-flask-sqlalchemy)
При использовании запроса на подобии этого:

```
q = db.session.query(Transaction). \
filter(Transaction.transaction_id != ReconciledTransaction.safe_withdraw_id)
```

Получаем такой `SQL`:

```
SELECT Transaction.* FROM Transaction, ReconciledTransaction
WHERE Transaction.transaction_id != ReconciledTransaction.safe_withdraw_id
```

Соответственно мы в любом случае делаем выборку из второй таблицы, и в таком случае в результат запроса попадают и те и те результаты, получается что фильтр 'как-бы игнорируется'.
Чтобы такого не происходила, нужно сделать выборку из второй таблицы(с которой сравниваем):

```
r_query = db.session.query(ReconciledTransaction.safe_withdraw_id). \
group_by(ReconciledTransaction.safe_withdraw_id)
r_ids = [x[0] for x in r_query]
```

А наш фильтр(в моём случае), будет выглядить следующим образом:

```
q = q.filter(Transaction.transaction_id.notin_(r_ids))
```

Как вариант, можно сделать вот так(говорят, лучше производительность):

```
q = q.filter(~session.query(ReconciledTransaction). \
filter(ReconciledTransaction.safe_withdraw_id == Transaction.id).exists())
```